# WPF Xaml StringFormat move decimal places for percentage but no %

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to get 0.1500 to display as 15.00.  My C# Property is a decimal and my xaml code is `<TextBox Text="{Binding ClosingRate, StringFormat={}{0:P2}}"/>` I want the format to move the decimal point 2 places to the right without having to change the decimal value nor have a leading 0. The "P2" format gets me close, but displays 20.00 %, and I don't want the percent sign.

Comment: You could use a converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it by simple StringFormat. It provides you **only** with some predefined options with interesting corner cases very little extensibility. What you want to do is effectively `*=100` your value and that kind is not supported directly neither by bindings nor by formats since that's arithmetic operation.

The fact that P/% actually also does *=100 is a probably just a coincidence. You could hack it to skip the % but it will not help you at all if in 3 days you have another place where you need to "move" it by a different number of digits.

The solution is ... to multiply the displayed value by 100. You don't need to alter the source value - it's just a matter of forcing the UI to read a different value than the source one.

Two easiest ways are:

- You can do it either in ViewModel, simply by exposing a new property i.e. `ClosingRateFormatted` that will be read-only and that will return ClosingRate*100 (just remember about notifying about changes to **both** properties now)
- You could use a IValueConverter and bind to ClosingRate as usual. Converter has 2 methods, Convert and ConvertBack and you can do *=100 in one, and /=100 in the other (if needed at all), and that will alter the value passed to/from the UI, but the source will not notice.

With Converter, no changes are needed in change-notifications (contrary to the first option), but using Converters is definitely a bit harder than just making a new readonly property.